# Returning to previous menu items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I've been working on a text based RPG battle sequence with vanilla JS in which buttons are used for player's to attack, use magic, etc. The buttons for both actions are created just fine and work properly in my project, but the problem comes when I use magic. There are multiple spells to choose from. As such, I set it up so that buttons will generate for each corresponding spell when the "Magic" button is clicked. These spell buttons also work, but after a spell is cast, I need to return to the original "Attack" and "Magic" buttons so that the next action in the battle sequence can take place. I'm not sure how to go about doing this with how i have set up my code for creating the buttons and am looking for some guidance on how to proceed:

```js
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-btns");


class Spell {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Person {
  constructor(magic) {
    this.magic = magic;
    this.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"];
  }
}

//spells
var fire = new Spell("Fire");
var meteor = new Spell("Meteor");
var cure = new Spell("Cure");

var playerSpells = [fire, meteor, cure];

// create player
let player1 = new Person(playerSpells);

function combatSequence() {
  while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < player1.actions.length; i++) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = player1.actions[i];
    // Add enemy attack functions in 'if' statements to keep combat going
    if (i === 0) {
      // Add event listener to atk btn
    } else if (i === 1) {
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log("Magic btn clicked");
        while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
          optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < player1.magic.length; j++) {
          const magButton = document.createElement("button");
          magButton.innerText = player1.magic[j].name;

          // create btn for spell
          if (j === 0) {
            magButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              console.log("Player uses fire");

            });
          } else if (j === 1) {
            magButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              console.log("Player uses meteor");
            });
          } else if (j === 2) {
            magButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
              console.log("Player uses heal");
              while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
                optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
              }
            });
          }
          optionButtonsElement.appendChild(magButton);
        }
      });
    }
    optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button);
  }
}

combatSequence();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Text Adventure</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="option-btns" class="btn-grid">
      <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
      <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated. There is most likely an easier option that i'm missing here. I tried to keep the code limited to only what was necessary, but if there is too much unncessary stuff, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: not clear where is the original magic and attack buttons are and how they were created and removed. Perhaps you should add whole code in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Just made a jsfiddle for it, added some comments for clarity. https://jsfiddle.net/OppulentHippo/53x6Lozg/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since combatSequence() function dynamically creates the buttons and click events, calling same function on click of specific spell (at the end of spell action code) will suffice

check the update below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bf5cke9/)

```js
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById("option-btns");

class Spell
{
    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Person
{
    constructor(magic)
    {
        this.magic = magic;
        this.actions = ["Attack","Magic"];
    }
}

//spells
var fire = new Spell("Fire");
var meteor = new Spell("Meteor");
var cure = new Spell("Cure");

var playerSpells = [fire, meteor, cure];

// create player
let player1 = new Person(playerSpells);

function combatSequence()
{
        // while loop removes default html buttons on screen, replaced by the 'attack' and 'magic' buttons
    while(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
    {
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
    }
        // creates the 'attack' and 'magic' buttons
    // 'i' is the index value for player1.actions[]
    for(var i = 0; i < player1.actions.length; i++)
    {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerText = player1.actions[i];
        // Player 'attack' buttons
        if(i === 0)
        {   
            button.addEventListener("click", () =>
            {
                    console.log("Player attacks");
            });
        }
        // Player 'magic' button
        else if(i === 1)
        {
            button.addEventListener("click", () => 
            {
                console.log("Magic btn clicked");
                while(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
                {
                    optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
                }
                
                // creates the 'spell' buttons after 'Magic' is clicked
                for(var j = 0; j < player1.magic.length; j++)
                {
                    const magButton = document.createElement("button");
                    magButton.innerText = player1.magic[j].name;

                    // creates spell 'fire' button
                    if(j === 0)
                    {
                        magButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
                        {
                            console.log("Player uses fire");
                            combatSequence();

                        });
                    }
                                        // creates meteor button
                    else if(j === 1)
                    {
                        magButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
                        {
                            console.log("Player uses meteor");
                            combatSequence();
                        });
                    }
                    // creates cure button
                    else if(j === 2)
                    {
                        magButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
                        {
                            console.log("Player uses heal");
                            // tried this here to see if the buttons would be removed on spell click
                            while(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
                            {
                                optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild);
                            }
                            combatSequence();
                        });
                    }
                    // adds spell buttons to html after 'magic' is clicked
                    optionButtonsElement.appendChild(magButton);
                }
            });
        }
        // adds the 'attack' and 'magic' buttons to html page
        optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button);
    }
}

combatSequence();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Text Adventure</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="option-btns" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="main(SOE).js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I remember trying that earlier and it breaking down. It must have been a different bug that was fixed at somepoint causing it to break because that is working now. Thank you very much for the help!